# Div don't stack vertically

Tags: html, css

On mobile I want my children div to stack up vertically.

Although, as the .content_hover is inside the main div, on mobile I want it to display below it, out of it.

How is this achievable ?

This is the markup I am using

```
<div class="columns bg_orange small-12 large-4 tile mobile-small-tile">
                    <h2 class="bottom_title no_bg hight_text">Current Patient Information</h2>
                    <div class="content_hover">
                        <p><br>Join us to discuss the IVF process and meet other people on the fertility journey.</p>
                        <a class="more_infos_hover" href="#">Register now ></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Do I need to position the content_hover absolute ? and push it down ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a div is a "block" element and so "siblings" will stack vertically.
So, I think you are asking how to get a "child" div to stack "below" its parent.
This would most easily be accomplished by changing the markup to reflect the structure you are trying to produce, which is "sibling" not "child".  If you can't, you will likely need to use relative positioning, which will make your layout dependent on the content :-(

Answer (score 0):

If `div.content_hover` is set to float, and there is nothing in it or after it that has `clear:both;`, and the parent div is set to `overflow:visible` (NOT `overflow:auto;`), then the parent should not extend to cover the child. Place the child div where you want using top margins.